# discord.py "get is not defined" error on command execution how to fix?

Tags: python, discord, bots

recently i've been coding my bot on python because i'm a beginner in bots etc etc and i've wanted to make a meme command because memes are kinda the bot's goal, and when i execute the memr command, it says everything is fine, but when someone runs the **meme** command, it just says "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'get' is not defined.
i don't see why or what is making this. i believe in StackOverflow's power!
here's my code:

````
import discord.ext
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import os
from datetime import datetime
import json
PREFIX = ("f!", "F!")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, description='the bot is currently being redesigned but you can use the commands below like f!say :)', case_insensitive=True)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    activity = discord.Game(name="f!help")
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=activity)
    print("bot is ready")

@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    for channel in guild.text_channels:
        if channel.permissions_for(guild.me).send_messages:
            await channel.send('thanks for inviting me to your server! try saying "f!help" to get my commands!')
            break

@bot.command(description="shows you my ping", brief="shows you my ping")
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'my ping is {bot.latency}ms!')

@bot.command(description="makes me say whatever you want", brief="makes me say whatever you want me to say")
async def say(ctx, *, message):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(f'{message}')

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        with open('users.json', 'r')as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        await self.update_data(users, member)

        with open('users.json', 'w')as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
      if not message.author.bot:
        with open('users.json','r')as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        await self.update_data(users, message.author)
        if(users[str(message.author.id)]['LastMessage'] < await self.to_integer(datetime.now())):
            await self.add_experience(users, message.author)
        await self.level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)


        with open('users.json', 'w')as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    async def update_data(self, users, user):
        if not str(user.id) in users:
            users[str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(user.id)]['level'] = 0
            users[str(user.id)]['LastMessage'] = await self.to_integer(datetime.now())

    async def add_experience(self, users, user):
        users[str(user.id)]['experience'] += random.randint(15,25)
        users[str(user.id)]['LastMessage'] = await self.to_integer(datetime.now())


    async def level_up(self, users, user,message):
        experience = users[str(user.id)]['experience']
        lvl = users[str(user.id)]['level']
        lvl_end = 5 * (lvl ** 2) + (50 * lvl) + 100
        print(user)
        print(f"Level:{lvl}")
        print(f"experience:{experience}")
        print(f"lvl_end: {lvl_end} ")



        if lvl_end <= experience:
            channel=self.client.get_channel(810855960133894154)
            await channel.send('{} has leveld up to level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl+1))
            users[str(user.id)]['level'] = lvl+1
            users[str(user.id)]['experience'] -= lvl_end



    async def to_integer(self, dt_time):
        answer = 100000000 * dt_time.year + 1000000 * dt_time.month + 10000 * dt_time.day + 100 * dt_time.hour + dt_time.minute
        return int(answer)

    @commands.command()
    async def rank(self,ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
        with open('users.json','r')as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        if user is None:
            if not str(ctx.author.id) in users:
                users[str(ctx.author.id)] = {}
                users[str(ctx.author.id)]['experience'] = 0
                users[str(ctx.author.id)]['level'] = 0
                users[str(ctx.author.id)]['LastMessage'] = await self.to_integer(datetime.now())
            user=ctx.author
            lvl = int(users[str(ctx.author.id)]['level'])
            exp = int(5 * (lvl ** 2) + (50 * lvl) + 100)
            embed = discord.Embed(Title=f"**{user}'s Rang**",Description=f"Experience: {lvl}/{5 * (lvl ** 2) + (50 * lvl) + 100}", color=0x0091ff)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{user.avatar_url}")
            embed.add_field(name=f"**{user}'s Rang**", value="  ", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Level", value=f"**{users[str(user.id)]['level']}**", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Experience", value=f"**{str(int(users[str(user.id)]['experience']))} / {exp}**",inline=True)
            embed.set_footer(text="Type more to level up!\nSpam is useless")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)


        else:
            if not str(user.id) in users:
                users[str(user.id)] = {}
                users[str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
                users[str(user.id)]['level'] = 0
                users[str(user.id)]['LastMessage'] = await self.to_integer(datetime.now())
            lvl = int(users[str(user.id)]['level'])
            exp=int(5 * (lvl ** 2) + (50 * lvl) + 100)
            embed=discord.Embed(Title=f"**{user}'s Rang**",Description=f"Experience: {lvl}/{5 * (lvl ** 2) + (50 * lvl) + 100}",color=0x0091ff)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{user.avatar_url}")
            embed.add_field(name=f"**{user}'s Rang**", value="  ", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Level",value=f"**{users[str(user.id)]['level']}**",inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Experience", value=f"**{str(int(users[str(user.id)]['experience']))} / {exp}**", inline=True)
            embed.set_footer(text="Type more to level up!\nSpam is useless")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        with open('users.json', 'w')as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def add_exp(self, ctx, user: discord.Member,nummer:int):
        with open('users.json', 'r')as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        if not ctx.author.bot:
            users[str(user.id)]['experience']+=int(nummer)
            await ctx.send("exp added")
        with open('users.json', 'w')as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    @commands.command()
    async def add_lvl(self, ctx, user: discord.Member,nummer:int):
        with open('users.json', 'r')as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        if not ctx.author.bot:
            users[str(user.id)]['level'] += int(nummer)
            await ctx.send("level added")
        with open('users.json', 'w')as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    @commands.command()
    async def add_database(self,ctx, user: discord.Member):
        with open('users.json', 'r')as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        if not str(user.id) in users:
            users[str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(user.id)]['level'] = 0
            users[str(user.id)]['LastMessage'] = await self.to_integer(datetime.now())
            await ctx.send("added to database!")
        else:
            await ctx.send("already in database!")

        with open('users.json', 'w')as f:
            json.dump(users, f)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(levels(client))

@bot.command(pass_context=True, description='some fresh memes for you!')
async def meme(ctx):
    content = get("https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/dankmemes").text
    data = json.loads(content,)
    meme = discord.Embed(title=data['title'], url=data['postLink'], color = colors.purple, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
    meme.set_image(url=f"{data['url']}")
    meme.set_footer(text=f'Used by {ctx.author.name}', icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.reply(embed=meme)

bot.run('bot token here')```
````

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [mre]. Also, what do you want `.get()` to do? It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. Perhaps you want to `import requests` and then use `requests.get()`?

Comment: Was my answer able to fix your problem?  If not, please give us more detail, including the desired behavior; if so, please mark my answer as correct

Comment: your answer was able to solve my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the function `meme`, you're calling a function `get` to fetch data from some URL.  However, the function `get` is not defined anywhere, resulting in the error `NameError: name 'get' is not defined`.  You likely need to import it from the `requests` module.

Add the following line to the top of your file:

```py
from requests import get
```

[This link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_get.asp) has more information on the `requests.get` method.